# How to create a custom tag for UITextField instead of tag id?

Tags: swift, tags, uitextfield

I am wondering if there's a way I can set a textfield's ID into something like "jobTextfield" instead of on the storyborad with "Tag: 0"

I have 5 textfields in my viewcontroller and I need a way to identify them instead of numbers so I can update my firebase console based on which textfield has text in them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is not possible to add a string in such storyboard's field (`tag` is an `Int`). However you might bind your tags with an enum like:

```
enum TextFieldType:Int {
    case jobTextfield
    case superTextField
    case magicTextField
    case awesomeTextField
    case weirdTextField
}
```

and then whenever you need to identify a specific `UITextField`:

```
self.view.viewWithTag(TextFieldType.jobTextfield.rawValue)
```